# Plot a 2D vector field with radial symmetry in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I computed a 2D vector field **U** = (u(x,y), v(x,y)) with radial symmetry, parametrized as (u,v) = a(r) (x,y) + b(r) (-y,x), where a(r), b(r) are given as solution of an IVP which I solved using
`Y = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(..., dense_output=True)`, which yields a solution function `Y.sol: r ↦ array([a(r),b(r)])`. To simplify, I give a similar function Y_sol here:

```
import numpy as np
Rmin, Rmax = 20, 200   # Y_sol isn't defined outside that range
Y_sol = lambda r: np.array([ 1-r/Rmin, 1 ])*np.exp(-r/Rmin)
```

To plot the vector field **U**, I finally did the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x,y = np.meshgrid( np.linspace(-Rmin, Rmax*2/3, 40), 
                   np.linspace(-2*Rmin, 2*Rmin, 30), sparse=True )
def uv(x,y):
    r = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
    a,b = Y_sol(r) if Rmin <= r <= Rmax else (0,0)
    return a*x-b*y, a*y+b*x
u,v = np.vectorize(uv, otypes=[float,float])(x,y)
plt.quiver(x,y,u,v)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot of the vector field]
This works, but is there a better way to do this? Specifically, is there a way (i.e., a suitable plotting function) allowing to avoid to compute and store the two potentially large arrays `u` and `v`, and rather provide just the function uv (or equivalent)?